# Convert uniform random generation to binomial

Tags: java, algorithm, math, distribution, genetic-algorithm

I have written the following function to implement a type of mutation(`creep`) in my `genetic algorithm` project. Since I've used java's inbuilt random generation library, the probability of getting every `index` is uniform. I've been asked to modify the function such way that it uses binomial distribution instead of uniform. As far as I googled, I couldn't find any example/tutorial that demonstrates conversion of uniform to binomial. How do I achieve it?

```
int mutationRate = 0.001;
public void mutate_creep() {
    if (random.nextDouble() <= mutationRate) {

        // uniform random generation
        int index = random.nextInt(chromoLen); 

        if(index%2 == 0) { // even index
            chromo[index] += 1;
        } else { // odd index
            chromo[index] -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I have already seen the solution at [A efficient binomial random number generator code in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561551/a-efficient-binomial-random-number-generator-code-in-java). Since my problem here is specific to `creep mutation algorithm`, I'm not sure how it can be applied directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A efficient binomial random number generator code in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561551/a-efficient-binomial-random-number-generator-code-in-java)

Comment: @pjs I understand that you've answered the duplicate marked question. FYI, I've seen it already and I cannot use it in my situation directly as I need it specifically for `creep mutation algorithm`. So please unmark the duplication flag and answer my problem here if u can.

Comment: A binomial is a binomial, and the linked answer tells you how to get those.  As currently worded, your question *is* a duplicate.  Sounds like your problem is not how to generate a binomial, but rather how to use it in your creep algorithm.

Comment: Is your intention to flip the bit at a specified index?  If so, your logic is off.  Suppose you select index 4 and the value of chromo[4] is currently 1, you'll update it to 2.  If your goal is to flip the bit, use `chromo[index] ^= 1;` regardless of even/odd index.

Comment: @pjs I'm implementing the function for my project and I had taken the reference from http://www.ijcsit.com/docs/Volume%205/vol5issue03/ijcsit20140503404.pdf, `section IV. Types of mutations - creep mutation`. As per the explanation I choose a random index and change its value between my lower and upper bound. For simplicity I've coded +/- 1 here but I've actually used another function call which returns a value between the bounds & then I add or subtract its value depending on whether the index is odd/even.

Comment: I still don't think you've clarified your question sufficiently to get meaningful answers.  The binomial distribution is a counting distribution, it describes the number of "successes" you observe when `n` independent trials are performed, each of which has probability `p` of success.  How do you plan to use that count?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Generating_binomial_random_variates), you do this:

> One way to generate random samples from a binomial distribution is to use an inversion algorithm. To do so, one must calculate the probability that P(X=k) for all values k from 0 through n. (These probabilities should sum to a value close to one, in order to encompass the entire sample space.) Then by using a pseudorandom number generator to generate samples uniformly between 0 and 1, one can transform the calculated samples U[0,1] into discrete numbers by using the probabilities calculated in step one.

I will leave it to you to "calculate the probability [...] for all values k from 0 through n". After that, it's a weighed distribution.

You can do that using a `TreeMap`, similar to how I show it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38803700/5221149).